# Remove first occurence of a word in a 2d list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list like this

```
[['a', 'word'],
['University', 'org'],
['of', 'org'],
['Michigan', 'org'], 
['Michigan', 'country']]
```

What I wanna do is If I find the word michigan at first iteration I will return the label and I will replace that word with something like "deleted" and when I iterate again I should find the list like this

```
[['a', 'word'],
['University', 'org'],
['of', 'org'],
['deleted', 'org'],
['Michigan', 'country']]
```

What I tried is

```
for i in range(len(list)):

    if word.lower()==list[i][0].lower():
        found= list[i][1]

        list.pop(i)
        list[i][0] = "deletedword"


        break
```

Comment: Don't do .pop(i), it remove the whole entry `['Michigan', 'org']`, you just whant to replace `Michigan` of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [['a', 'word'], ['University', 'org'], ['of', 'org'], ['Michigan', 'org'], ['Michigan', 'country']]

toReplace = 'Michigan'
for i in l:
    if i[0].lower() == toReplace.lower():
        i[0] = "deletedword"    #No need to Pop just replace.
        break
print(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[['a', 'word'], ['University', 'org'], ['of', 'org'], ['deletedword', 'org'], ['Michigan', 'country']]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a generator expression to find the position of first `"Michigan"`. Replace it with required word:

```
lst = [['a', 'word'], ['University', 'org'], ['of', 'org'], ['Michigan', 'org'], ['Michigan', 'country']]

try:
    pos = next((i, x.index('Michigan')) for i, x in enumerate(lst) if 'Michigan' in x)
    lst[pos[0]][pos[1]] = 'deleted'

except StopIteration:
    print('There is no Michigan in the list')

print(lst)

# [['a', 'word'], 
#  ['University', 'org'], 
#  ['of', 'org'], 
#  ['deleted', 'org'], 
#  ['Michigan', 'country']]
```

Comment: `next` without a second argument is better wrapped in a `try` loop since it can raise an `StopIteration` Exception.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I've thought about doing it. But since it works for OP's input, I thought I shouldn't complicate it much. But, sure will do.

Answer (score 0):

You wish to `break` out of a nested `for` loop. One readable way to achieve this is using a function and the `return` statement:

```
def remove_first_el(A, k='Michigan'):
    for i in range(len(A)):                         # iterate outer lists
        for j in range(len(A[i])):                  # iterate inner lists
            if A[i][j].casefold() == k.casefold():  # ignore case for comparison
                A[i][j] = 'deleted'
                return A

res = remove_first_el(lst)

print(res)

[['a', 'word'],
 ['University', 'org'],
 ['of', 'org'],
 ['deleted', 'org'],
 ['Michigan', 'country']]
```

If you need "Michigan" to the first element of your sublist, you can modify your function accordingly:

```
def remove_first_el_zero_pos(A, k='Michigan'):
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i][0].casefold() == k.casefold():
            A[i][0] = 'deleted'
            return A
```